# ExtJS4 Grid with RowExpander

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I need to display a form in the rowexpander. In order to do that I am planning to create a temporary div as part of rowexpander and then attach a form to it during expandbody event. However, I am confused as to how to register expandbody listener for RowExpander.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you don't want to use the regular roweditor? Or popup a window with the record loaded into the form?

---

EDIT:
If that's all you want then just follow the example from [Sencha](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/grid/grid-plugins.html).
Essentially all you do is specify a template of how you want your data rendered in the plugin config. You don't need to listen to expand events just to render data.

```
plugins: [{
            ptype: 'rowexpander',
            rowBodyTpl : [
                '<p><b>Company:</b> {company}</p><br>',
                '<p><b>Summary:</b> {desc}</p>'
            ]
        }],
```

Comment: I think I did not explain correctly. All I wanted was to show more details about the row expanded. I do not want to edit a row instead I want to show more details about the expanded row in a table or form. Thanks

Comment: i need in second  grid row  rowBodyTpl please help me

Answer (score 2):

Use 'pluginId' property to get access to the RowExpander plugin object.

Here is an example taken from [the RowExpander docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ux.RowExpander-cfg-pluginId)

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 2,
        pluginId: 'cellplugin'
    }]
});



// later on:

var plugin = grid.getPlugin('cellplugin');
```